# Setting a session value through RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, rspec

My current code looks like this:

**/spec/support/spec_test_helper.rb**

```
module SpecTestHelper
  def login_admin
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, type: 0)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end
```

**/app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
def current_user
  if session[:user_id].nil?
    render plain: 'Error', status: :unauthorized
  else
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, session is always empty in the current_user method. Is there a way of controlling the session through RSpec?

Comment: for feature spec or controller specs?

Comment: how/where do you call `login_admin` ?

Comment: in banners_controller_spec, in an it "..." do block

Comment: weird you dont have to do anything else then. (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/16d7f6d08d0d64d56409f63e0d97a5b6b0307d59/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L243-L248)

Comment: Could it be that I'm doing the check in a before_action filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will change based on the spec type. For example, a `feature` spec will not allow you to directly modify the session. However, a `controller` spec will.

You will need to include the [helper methods module](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-2/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module) into your example group. Say you have a `WidgetsController`:

```
require 'support/spec_test_helper'

RSpec.describe WidgetsController, type: :controller do
  include SpecTestHelper

  context "when not logged in" do
    it "the request is unauthorized" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:unauthorized)
    end
  end

  context "when logged in" do
    before do
      login_admin
    end

    it "lists the user's widgets" do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

You can also [automatically include the module](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-2/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module) into all specs, or [specific specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-2/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module#include-a-module-in-only-some-example-groups) by using [metadata](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-2/docs/metadata).

I often do this by adding the configuration changes into the file which defines the helper methods:

**/spec/support/spec_test_helper.rb**

```
module SpecTestHelper
  def login_admin
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, type: 0)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include SpecTestHelper, type: :controller
end
```

Comment: I had the same issue and it didn't help me, I am getting the same error.  "undefined local variable or method `session' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups:"

Comment: You should include require 'rails_helper' to the SpecTestHelper